# Trying to find operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$ be Hilbert spaces and let $V=B(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{K})$. Fixed $T_i \in V$ for $i=1, 2$.

> Define $T: V \oplus V \to V \oplus V$ as $$T( v_1, v_2) = (T_1T_2^*v_1, T_2T_1^* v_2) $$ then $$ \|T \|= \|T_1 T_2^* \|$$ Here $ V \oplus V$ is equipped with Euclidean norm.

I can see that $\|T \| \geq  \|T_1 T_2^* \|$ but i am unable to see the other side. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one direction
\begin{align}
\lVert T \rVert &= \sup_{\lVert(v_1, v_2) \rVert =1} \lVert T(v_1, v_2) \rVert  \\
&= \sup_{\lVert(v_1, v_2) \rVert =1} \lVert(T_1 T_2^* v_1, T_2 T_1^* v_2) \rVert  \\
&= \sup_{\lVert(v_1, v_2) \rVert =1} \left(\lVert T_1 T_2^* v_1\rVert ^2 +  \lVert  T_2 T_1^* v_2\rVert^2\right)^{1/2} \\
&\geq \sup_{\lVert(v_1, v_2) \rVert =1} \left(\lVert T_1 T_2^* v_1\rVert ^2\right)^{1/2}  \\
&= \sup_{\lVert(v_1, v_2) \rVert =1}  \lVert  T_1 T_2^* v_1 \rVert \\
&= \sup_{\lVert v_1\rVert =1}  \lVert  T_1 T_2^* v_1 \rVert  \\
&=  \lVert  T_1 T_2^*\rVert.
\end{align}
For the other direction
\begin{align}
\lVert T \rVert &= \sup_{\lVert(v_1, v_2) \rVert =1} \left(\lVert T_1 T_2^* v_1\rVert ^2 +  \lVert  T_2 T_1^* v_2\rVert^2\right)^{1/2} \\
&\leq \sup_{\lVert(v_1, v_2) \rVert =1} \left(\lVert T_1 T_2^*\rVert^2\lVert v_1\rVert^2+\lVert T_2 T_1^*\rVert^2\lVert v_2\rVert^2\right)^{1/2}  \\
&=\lVert  T_1 T_2^*\rVert \sup_{\lVert(v_1, v_2) \rVert =1} (\lVert v_1 \rVert^2+\lVert v_2\rVert^2)^{1/2} \\
&=  \lVert  T_1 T_2^*\rVert.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

In general if $$T(v_1,v_2)=(Av_1,Bv_2)$$ then $\|T\|=\max\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}.$ The inequality $"\ge "$ is easy as
$$T(v,0)=(Av,0),\quad T(0,v)=(0,Bv)$$
On the other hand
$$\|T(v_1,v_2)\|^2=\|Av_1|^2+\|Bv_2\|^2\\ \le
\|A\|^2\|v_1\|^2+\|B\|^2\|v_2\|^2
\\ \le \max\{\|A\|^2,\|B\|^2\}\,(\|v_1\|^2+\|v_2\|^2)$$
Thus $\|T\|\le \max\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}.$

The proof can be extended to longer direct sums. The conclusion is the same for the norm of the diagonal matrix in the euclidean space.